# nav bar width is higher than its parent div

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a navigation bar which should fit inside a div id called `#page_wrap`
itd width is 980px when i tried with firebug i am seeing that `#nav` selection is bigger than `#page_wrap`.Why this is happening.

my intention is the nav bar should not go outside the `#page_wrap`

Here is the Code

**HTML**

```
<div id="page_wrap">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu9</a></li>
        </ul> <!-- END Navigation Bar-->
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div> <!-- END page_wrap -->
```

**CSS**

```
ul#nav {
    list-style: none;
    width:980px;
    height:35px;
    background:#000000;
}
ul#nav li a {
    float:left;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:105px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-right: 2px solid #979797;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background: #979797;
}
#page_wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:980px;
}
```

[image: Why there are empty spaces in the start and End]
See the image it has empty spaces in start and end. Why there are empty spaces in the start and End. How to avoid those things. I believe this is what causing a problem of bigger than its parent.

How to Remove Start and End emtpy Spaces and how to place `#nav` inside #page_wrap  exactly which means it should not go out from `#page_wrap`. Any Help?

[Check this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kxtfE/)

Comment: You simply haven’t eliminated the default padding UL gets from the browser stylesheet.

Comment: Correct, setting `padding: 0;` should fix the problem.

Comment: Oh i see. Browser has default padding value for `ul` tag...Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove default padding for the UL.

```
ul#nav{padding:0;}
```

Comment: The spacing on the right is inherited from the width of the UL

Comment: You could have just edited your answer. No need for a comment.

Comment: So by giving separate id to Menu9 and setting the border to none using the id will help. Right? @Dale

Comment: @sun you can use the :last-child pseudoclass to target Menu9 and set its border to none.

Comment: Yes you can just use ul#nav li:last-child a{border-right:none;}

Comment: Thanks for last child selector. @Pais and Dale

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wrzvt/1/)**

**css**

```
  *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul#nav {
    list-style: none;
    width:980px;
    height:35px;
    background:#000000;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;

}
ul#nav li a {
    float:left;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:105px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-right: 2px solid #979797;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background: #979797;
}

#page_wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:980px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this at the start of your css

```
* {
padding: 0;
}
```